# Substitute word in a specific line with multiple keyword check

Tags: bash, file, sed

I need to modify a lot of .pdb file for work and i need to script this operation to not waste time doing it manually every time.

I got a file with this particular format (this is an extract from the file, you can see full file [here](https://files.rcsb.org/view/1X8W.pdb)):

```
ATOM   5210  C4    G B  96      10.157 -47.431 -42.832  1.00 43.97           C  
ATOM   5211  P     G B  97      11.305 -41.644 -44.835  1.00 26.64           P  
ATOM   5212  OP1   A B  97      12.654 -41.242 -44.460  1.00 26.64           O  
ATOM   5213  OP2   A B  97      10.167 -41.192 -44.014  1.00 26.64           O  
ATOM   5214  O5'   A B  97      11.079 -41.206 -46.340  1.00 26.64           O
```

In particular for each file i need to substitute the word 'OP1' in third column with another keyword, but ONLY if the first column display 'ATOM' and there is a particular number on sixth column.

I tried to script it with sed but I didn't get any decent result.

Hope anyone can help

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers. The goal is that you add some code of your own to your question to show at least the research effort you made to solve this yourself.

Comment: Please add your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simply way to start:

improved:

`awk '{if ($1=="ATOM" && $6=="410" && $3=="OP2")sub($3,"XXX"); print }'`  1X8W.pdb

Comment: value check for column 6 is not verified with this answer.

Comment: Thanks! it Works exactly i hope for my purpose!

Comment: `awk '($1=="ATOM" && $6=="410" && $3=="OP2"){sub($3,"XXX"); print}' 1X8W.pdb`. Awk has its `condition { action }` syntax for a reason. I'm not saying this is a good approach, of course, since it relies on the value of $3 not appearing as part of any earlier field. A simple `$3="XXX"` would be better.

Answer (score 0):

Try this script

```
while read p; do
    value1=`echo $p | cut -d' ' -f1`
    value2=`echo $p | cut -d' ' -f3`
    value3=`echo $p | cut -d' ' -f6`
    if [ "$value1" == "ATOM" ] && [ $value3 == 97 ]; then
        if [ "$value2" == "OP1" ]; then
            echo $p | awk '{gsub("OP1", "newtext", $0); print}'
        fi
    fi
done < 1X8W.pdb
```

Change `newtext` with the text you want to be replaced for OP1. Also, change the $value3 comparison number from 97 to anything else if you are checking for any other number as well.

Comment: Huh?? As soon as you find at least one instance of `$value1 == "ATOM"` etc, that `sed` will change **ALL** instances of `OP1` to `newtext`, no matter where it is in the file. And it will be painfully slow.

Comment: You are correct, this needs to be rectified. Will update again with improvement.

Comment: Did you know you can read more fields in one go: `read -r f1 f2 f3 f4 f5 f6 rest_of_line` ?

Comment: See [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice) for some (but not all) of the issues with this script.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like this might be what you're trying to do:

```
awk '($1=="ATOM") && ($6==97) { sub(/^OP1$/,"other",$3); print }' file
```

but without more details in your question we're all just guessing and can't test it.